# Issue with applying an SSL cert (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, ssl-certificate

I'm running a windows server 2008 r2 with apache 2 installed runnign svn.  I've had to buy a new public cert.  I've overwritten the old .crt and .key file with the new files and then restarted the Apache service.  It all restarts fine with no errors, but when I browse to the site I still get a certificate error and it's still trying to reference the old certificate.  The old files have definitely been replaced.

I did this same process for another server I have and it worked.  I have inherited a server from someone now out of contact, so I'm not really sure on where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have cleared the browser cache? You could try using openssl client to view more debugging info.

Comment: yes, definitely cleared.  I wondering if I should just start again with a new cert.